# How to select different events from different bags without events crashing?

Tags: java

I have the following objects:

```
Pool:
-Assignments
-Code

Assignment:
-Name
-Code
-Indicator (unique)
-Events
-Number of weeks

Event:
-Weekdays
-Start Time
-End time
```

I have N pools of objects that share the same 'Code', the user must enter a list of 'Codes' and the system must respond with 5 lists of Assignments, each lists must contain 1 assignment of each pool chosen by the user, without events crashing.

I have tried approaching with brute force getting a high time complexity and with dynamic programming using a multi backpack approximation, is there any library or technique to solve this problem with a lower complexity?

Comment: This sounds a lot like process scheduling

Comment: Why is the `java` tag used - there's no code provided and the question doesn't look like it needs any language tag.